# SQL- Regex to check if fields have alphanumeric characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, hana

I'm trying to use RegEx for a case statement to check if a column starts with Alphanumeric characters or not. The below code is not working.

If either the Customer or the Vendor column has Alphanumeric characters then the TYPE column is set as 'Internal'. If the two columns have only numbers then type is 'External'

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| Customer | Vendor   | TYPE     |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 0488859  |          | External |
+----------+----------+----------+
| P3849500 |          | Internal |
+----------+----------+----------+
|          | 58384899 | External |
+----------+----------+----------+
|          | P3902034 | Internal |
+----------+----------+----------+
|          |          | NULL     |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

**Code**

```
         CASE 
            WHEN Customer LIKE '%[A-Z]%' OR Vendor LIKE '%[A-Z]%' THEN 'INTERNAL'
            WHEN Customer LIKE '%[^0-9]%' OR Vendor LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN 'EXTERNAL'
            ELSE 'NULL'
         END AS TYPE
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `LIKE '[A-Z]%'` if you only want to check the first character?

Comment: Do you have to use Regex?  It seems that Is_Numeric() would serve just as well here.

Comment: SQL Server and SAP Hana are two very different database systems. Which one are you really using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[^0-9]` means the regex no number.

use `[0-9]` instead of `[^0-9]`

```
CREATE TABLE T (
   Customer VARCHAR(50),
   Vendor  VARCHAR(50)
);
insert into t values ('0488859','');
insert into t values ('P3849500','');
insert into t values ('','0488859');
insert into t values ('','P3902034');
insert into t values ('','');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *, CASE 
            WHEN Customer LIKE '%[A-Z]%' OR Vendor LIKE '%[A-Z]%' THEN 'INTERNAL'
            WHEN Customer LIKE  '%[0-9]%' OR Vendor LIKE '%[0-9]%' THEN 'EXTERNAL'
            ELSE 'NULL'
         END AS TYPE 
FROM T
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0bc83/1/0)**:

```
| Customer |   Vendor |     TYPE |
|----------|----------|----------|
|  0488859 |          | EXTERNAL |
| P3849500 |          | INTERNAL |
|          |  0488859 | EXTERNAL |
|          | P3902034 | INTERNAL |
|          |          |     NULL |
```

Comment: For some reason it gives me null in the column type

Comment: In which reason, could you give me some sample? Because it seem to work in sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need separate checks for numeric and alphabetic: Since you state

> If the two columns have only numbers then type is 'External'

With test data:

```
WITH CustomerVendors(Customer, Vendor) as (
                SELECT '0488859', null
    UNION ALL   SELECT 'P3849500', null
    UNION ALL   SELECT NULL, '58384899'
    UNION ALL   SELECT NULL, 'P3902034'
)
```

You just need to check if the fields contain a letter. So your query becomes:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE
        WHEN Customer LIKE '%[A-Z]%' THEN 'Internal'
        WHEN Vendor LIKE '%[A-Z]%' THEN 'Internal'
        ELSE 'External'
    END [TYPE]
FROM CustomerVendors
```

Which gives you:

```
Customer    Vendor      Type
0488859     NULL        External
P3849500    NULL        Internal
NULL        58384899    External
NULL        P3902034    Internal
```

Of course, I wonder why you have a a table set up the way you do: Shouldn't you be storing vendors and customers in a separate table?

Comment: I'm pulling the two columns from two separate tables into a single query

Comment: Kind of a separate thought, but why don't you have one column in your query (e.g. `CustomerOrVendorID`, and a separate column that identifies the entity type (customer or vendor)? That makes your logic for identifying internal vs. external cleaner (regardless of what logic you go with).

Answer (score 0):

You just need one expression `'[0-9]%'` This will get the Customers ID which starts with numbers. Then the rest would be in your favor. As from your example you only have two conditions (starts with a number or starts with a letter). This could be done like this :

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
    WHEN Customer LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN 'External' ELSE 'Internal' 
  END [Type]
```

if you the actual data is similar to the provided example, and you want to include both customer and vendors in the same condition, you can do something like this :

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
    WHEN CASE WHEN Customer = '' THEN Vendor ELSE Customer END  LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN 'External' ELSE 'Internal' 
  END [Type]
```

If the customer or vendor has NULL and not empty strings, then you can do it with `ISNULL` function like this

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
    WHEN ISNULL(Customer,Vendor) LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN 'External' ELSE 'Internal' 
  END [Type]
```

if Customer and Vendor have different pattern (say customer only numbers and vendors would have vendor name with some sequential number, then you need to separate the conditions and not join them in one condition.